# Lions vs. dogs for defense?

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara, animals

I am looking for a statement in Gemara or Halacha that one may own a dog for defense but not a lion. Does any of you know the source?

Comment: Seems like you're thinking of the the gem. BK 79b (see Yam Shel Shlomo BK ch. 7 §45) and codified in SA (CM 409) but don't know where (if at all) a lion is specifically excluded.

Answer (score 2):

I found the source, I think. Mishnah Bava Kama 1:4. R. Eliezer holds that one could train a lion, the חכמים disagree.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, user3140521! Remember you can edit your profile and make your username a bit more personal. Also, thanks for your answer! We hope you'll stick around.